# How to read custom data format in Tensorflow using FixedLengthRecordReader?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am doing some experiments while reading data using **Tensorflow** queue, and I would like to ask a simple case below.

Assume my binary data files have a list of a `float` value (4byte) and `boolean` label (1byte). For example

```
3.4 true 2.1 false 0.3 true ..."
```

Following is my trial. I would like to cut a 4-bytes part (converting to `float`), and 1-byte part (converting to `bool`). However, I am not sure how to use `decode_raw()` in this case. If I use `uint8`, it cuts every byte.

If it is wrong to use `FixedLengthRecordReader`, what is a simple way to do this? Can anyone help me?

```
# Dimensions of data
data_bytes = 4
label_bytes = 1  
record_bytes = data_bytes + label_bytes

reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_bytes)
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

value = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)
data_part = tf.cast(tf.slice(value, [0], [data_bytes]), tf.float32)
label_part = tf.cast(tf.slice(value, [data_bytes], [label_bytes]), tf.bool)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
data_part = tf.bitcast(tf.slice(value, [0], [data_bytes]), tf.float32)
```

i.e., use `tf.bitcast` to convert 4 uint8s into a float32, instead of using `tf.cast`.

Comment: For those who may wonder, this suggestion works well. Thanks.